# raffle command, charging per ticket discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to make a command in which the user uses it to buy a specified quantity of tickets. However, I'm having a problem with controlling the number of coins to be taken from the buyer.

I set it so that each ticket costs 5 thousand coins, but when he tries to buy 2 tickets, he's only charged 5 thousand coins (instead of 10k).

Code

```js
run: async (bot, message, args) => {
  let author = await db.fetch(`money_${message.author.id}_${message.guild.id}`);
  var money = await db.get(`money_${message.author.id}_${message.guild.id}`);
  var conta = await db.get(`money_${message.author.id}_${message.guild.id}`);
  if (!message.guild.member(bot.user).hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
    return message.channel.send("Eu não tenho permissão suficiente.");
  }

  if (message.content.includes("-")) {
    // para que não ocorra um futuro abuso, pois menos com menos gera mais
    return message.reply(`você está tentando abusar?`);
  }

  if (5000 > conta) {
    // Caso o número que o usuário deseja apostar seja maior que o que ele possui na database
    return message.reply(`Você não possui **5000 Moedas** para participar!`);
  }

  if (author < 5000) parseInt(args[0]);
  // puxando um membro para quem iremos adicionar
  let member = message.author;

  let remoVeu = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    .setDescription(
      `**<@${message.author.id}>** comprou \`1 ticket\` por **5000 Moedas**!\nPara adicionar \`1 ticket\` use o comando !raffle <@${message.author.id}> 1`
    );
  bot.channels.cache.get("763752044464439311").send("<@&759003907879206935>");
  bot.channels.cache.get("763752044464439311").send(remoVeu);
  db.subtract(`money_${member.id}_${message.guild.id}`, author); // adicionando na database, a quantia
  db.add(`rifa_761171065006456833_${message.guild.id}`, author);

  let noEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(
      `<@${message.author.id}>, você comprou \`1 ticket\` com sucesso.`
    )
    .setColor("GREEN")
    .setFooter("Quanto mais você comprar, mais chances você tem!");
  message.channel.send(message.member, { embed: noEmbed }).then((msg) => {
    // E, como quase todo arquivo, usaremos a função 'then', nomeada de 'msg'
    msg.react("✅"); // Reagindo com o emoji de legal
    // Criando um filtro, verificando quem clicou no emoji, e vendo se o ID do mesmo é compativel com o do autor
    let filtro = (reaction, usuario) =>
      reaction.emoji.name === "✅" && usuario.name;
  });
};
```

Comment: @Lioness100 I'm not getting any error, but as I explained the command is to buy ticket 1 ticket costs 5 thousand coins, and if you buy 10 ticket it only takes 5 thousand coins from the user when it was to take 50 thousand coins

Comment: @Lioness100 I'm not getting any error, but as I explained the command is to buy ticket 1 ticket costs 5 thousand coins, and if you buy 10 ticket it only takes 5 thousand coins from the user when it was to take 50 thousand coins

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I realized that as I was editing the question.

Comment: Could you specify which question removes the money from the buyer's wallet? I presume it takes place on this line: `db.subtract(\`money_${member.id}_${message.guild.id}\`, author)`, but I don't actually see where you specify the value to subtract.

Comment: @Lioness100 `if (author < 5000) parseInt(args[0]);` 
he takes 5,000 regardless of how many tickets you buy, he had to take 5,000 for each ticket